# How to change docker node hostname

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I got connected nodes to my swarm, but all of these nodes got same hostname "docker-desktop", any idea how to change hostname in Docker Destkop?

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
pl0b3aa6vit00unxqzzbmyhbe     docker-desktop      Down                Active                                  19.03.5
w2t3uk2gjnpn33g0sktp8le1s     docker-desktop      Ready               Active                                  19.03.5
yys70s53u2iujqa8oq161c2fv     docker-desktop      Down                Active                                  19.03.5
hyuu5n7o7c78uf2nf96680og6 *   swarmpit            Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.5
c5wrnvu25dbm655yn2dvir0pn     vpn                 Ready               Active                                  19.03.5
```

*Docker Desktop latest version on Windows 10 with Hyper-V*

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a limitation at the time of this writing when using Docker Desktop.  Here is a feature request.  https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7626

You can get around it if using a WSL2 distro and running docker that way instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the limitation that [leukosaima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245678/leukosaima) mentions still holds at the end of 2023; the feature request mentioned is closed and seems to have been rejected. It is perhaps worth noting that the issue affects MacOS versions of Docker desktop also.

A common use-case for referring to node names is specifying placement constraints, e.g. `node.hostname==my-host`. The non-uniqueness of docker desktop hostnames causes a problem here. An alternative approach is to suggest placement constraints via *labels*, as in `node.labels.hostname==my-host`. This will work if you label your node e.g. via `docker node update --add-label hostname-my-host`. More generally, an approach using labels to specify service function or role might be more maintainable / portable.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change the host name of your host machines (swarm nodes) and then restart the docker service on each node.

- set new host name using command 
  **hostname** new-host-name
- restart docker service
  sudo service docker restart